# Having issue with making an object in C++

Tags: c++

Ok so I'm working on this little code and I've made two classes, `advString` and `advString_stream`. Here are the classes:

```
class advString
{
public:
    string s_value;
    int i_value;
    advString(string s) : s_value(s) {}
    advString(int i)    : i_value(i) {}
};
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class advString_stream
{
public:
    advString get();
    void putback(advString as);
private:
    advString buffer;
    bool full = false;
};
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And then, later down in the code, I define this object:

```
advString_stream ads;
```

It seems like it should work for me, but whenever I run the code, it gives me this error:

> 'advStream::advStream(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function

So can someone help me? I can't seem to make an advString_stream without the compiler complaining.

Comment: For efficiency `advString(string s)` would be better as `advString(const string& s)`

Comment: On an unrelated note, are you sure you want the `advString_stream::get` function return *by value* and not by reference?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg What do you mean 'by reference'? It's meant to get the advString either a) out of the buffer or b) from cin

Comment: Assuming that the `get` function returns `buffer`, then it will return a *copy* of the `buffer` object. Any changes to the returned object will only be for that object and not reflected in the `buffer` member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the contained `advString` object (the `buffer` member) doesn't have a default constructor, you need to explicitly provide a `advString_stream` constructor to properly construct the `buffer` object.

Something like

```
class advString_stream
{
public:
    advString_stream()
        : buffer(someArgumentHere)  // Using constructor initializer list
    {}

    ...
};
```

Comment: And how would I do that?

Comment: @jibboom Updated answer

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare and implement a default constructor, If you declare and implement a other contructor.

Comment: How exactly would I do that?